# Interpretation of javascript code - Tilde symbol in front of ternary IF operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was checking the code of respons.js in express and came across this code:

```
res.contentType =
res.type = function(type){
  return this.set('Content-Type', ~type.indexOf('/')
    ? type
    : mime.lookup(type));
};
```

My question is what does the `~` operator do in front of the `type.indexOf()` statement? What is its purpose and when is it used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators#.7E_%28Bitwise_NOT%29), although its use here is quite opaque.

It is being used to transform a `-1` result from `indexOf` (i.e., string not found) into a `0`, which is a falsy value (since `~-1 == 0`, and `0` is false in a boolean context), and it lets all other values remain truthy.

It could have been written more clearly as `(type.indexOf('/') != -1) ? ... : ...`

In plain English, it says, "Treat a `-1` result (i.e., if `/` was not found) from `indexOf` as `false`; otherwise, treat the result as `true`".

Comment: In effect, `~type.indexOf('/')` means "`type` contains string `/`".

Comment: For readability, you could patch the string prototype: `String.prototype.contains = function(s) { return ~this.indexOf(s); }`, giving `type.contains('/')`

Comment: One doubt, what happens if 0 occurs instead of -1. Do it will hit 0 in any case ? so what happen while transforming 0 result from indexof into ??

Comment: @AgnesGruSteven When `indexOf` returns `0`, that indicates a match has been found (at the beginning of the string), so you want a truthy value to indicate the presence of a match. `~0` is equal to `-1`, which is a truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde is the *bitwise* NOT operator, just as `!` is the *logical* NOT operator. You may want to take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators#.7E_%28Bitwise_NOT%29) of the operator on Mozilla Developer Network for its full usage and meaning.